# Is this Makefile correct?

Tags: c, makefile

I've been asked to do a makefile and I've done this:

```
# La siguiente no es necesariamente requerida, se agrega para
# mostrar como funciona.

.SUFFIXES: .o .c
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<


# Macros

CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
SRC = main.c metbasicos.c metbasicos.h metintermedios.c metintermedios.h metavanzados.c metavanzados.h
OBJ = main.c metbasicos.c metintermedios.c metavanzados.c


# Reglas explicitas

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o p1 $(OBJ)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) main

# Reglas implicitas

metbasicos.o: metbasicos.c metbasicos.h
metintermedios.o: metintermedios.c metintermedios.h
metavanzados.o: metavanzados.c metavanzados.h
main.o: main.c metbasicos.h metintermedios.h metavanzados.h
```

Is it correct?

To compile I usually use the following command:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic main.c metbasicos.c metintermedios.c metavanzados.c -o p1.exe
```

if I make some tests with:

`make`
`./p1 < input.txt`

Works fine, but i'm not sure if it is a correct implementation.

Someone could tell me if I'm making some serious error?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why did you attempt to redefine the rule to turn .c into .o?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Because I used a makefile as a template, from another person, and I have a little idea of how they work ... could you tell me which lines are unnecessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any serious errors here, but there are some odd things.  As Ignacio points out, you don't really need to redefine the compile rule if you don't want to.  But the reason you probably did do it is you are mixing up C and C++ a bit.

You are building `.c` files, which are C code by convention, with `g++`, which is a C++ compiler, which is odd.  If you are really building C code, you should compile it with `gcc`.  If you're really building C++ code you should rename your files to end with `.cpp` or `.cc` or similar.  Also, the GNU make variables for the C++ compiler are `CXX`, not `CC`, and the variable for the flags is `CXXFLAGS` not `CFLAGS`.

Also, your `all` target should depend on `p1` and the `p1` target should contain the link:

```
.PHONY: all
all: p1
p1: $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o p1 $(OBJ)
```

Otherwise `p1` will be re-linked every time you run `make` even if no changes were made.

There are other more advanced things you can add, like automatic construction of header file prerequisites, etc.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the program must be written in `C` and compiled with `g++`.

This is how my teacher wants us to work.

Comment: That's ... weird.  I would be skeptical of this in general since C != C++.  In other words, not all legal C programs are legal C++ programs (and obviously vice versa).  Using the wrong compiler can lead to incorrect understanding of the language (IMO).  Of course I'm not the one giving you a grade :-p

Answer (score 1):

`$(CFLAGS)` are *Compilation* flags : they are used when compiling your `.c` source files into `.o` object files.

Using `$(CFLAGS)` when doing `$(CC) -o $(OBJ)` is not common practice, though it works fine. A correct way would be to use `$(LDFLAGS)` the flags for the linking process putting all `.o` together with the possible libs you are using into a binary executable.

Usually $(CFLAGS) contain compilation options such as the ones you use, and $(LDFLAGS) contain linking options such as `-L. -lpersonal` for loading a file named `libpersonal.a` in the same directory as the makefile.

Also, I'd advise you to use `+=` to your `CFLAGS` declaration to keep existing CFLAGS if there already are some.

The `.c.o` rule is useful if you don't want to bother setting a rule for each file, what you did at the bottom. The best practice would be to define a custom rule for each file, adding header files included by the source file as a dependancy of that rule. This way, the makefile will manage to only recompile files that *needs* to be, because of a change in the source *or* a change in the included headers. Of course this needs a thorough analysis of the source files **and** a regular modification when you change the header files you include in each of your sources.

Comment: It's not uncommon (indeed, it's the default behavior) to include `CFLAGS` in the link line, so I wouldn't agree that it's not correct.  Sometimes the linker wants to know things about `CFLAGS` such as `-g`, `-pthread`, flags for code coverage, etc.